# Setting the width of dropdowns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the following given fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HVHV2/

I would like all the dropdowns to be the same width as the text for the first entry.
Like for first dropdown the width for the dropdown must be equivalent to width of "By Category".
Due to some reasons it is taking the width of one of the options inside it.

Can anybody correct this up?
I am using bootstrap too.

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <span class="inlineControl">
        <select name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$MainContent$contentFilters$drpCategory" id="drpCategory">
    <option value="0">By Category</option>
    <option value="application-programming-interfaces-apis">Application Programming Interfaces (APIs)</option>
    <option value="application-service-providers-asps">Application Service Providers (ASPs)</option>
        </select>
   </span>
    <span class="inlineControl">
        <select name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$MainContent$contentFilters$drpUsers" id="drpUsers">
    <option value="0">By Actor In role</option>
    <option value="not-role">(Not role)</option>
    <option value="tom_cruise">Tom Cruise</option>
    <option value="Angelina">Angelina Jolie</option>
    <option value="Heidi">Heidi Klum</option>
        </select>
        </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited per comment:** Check out http://jsfiddle.net/HVHV2/2/.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ddl = $('#drpCategory');
    var savedOptions = [];

    var ddlOptions = ddl.find('option');
    for (var i = 1; i < ddlOptions.length; i++) {
        var curOption = ddlOptions[i];
        savedOptions.push(curOption);
        $(curOption).remove();
    }

    ddl.width(ddl.width());


    for (var i = 0; i < savedOptions.length; i++) {
        ddl.append(savedOptions[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry you made the width equal for both dropdowns. I want the first drop down to take only width the width of the first option not the width of the longest option.

Comment: Edited per your comment.

Comment: Whew!! that looks a lot of code.. was looking for some css solution

Comment: As other posters noted, you're not going to get a drop-down whose width is always the width of the first item in CSS alone.  You can set a manual width via CSS which may happen to be the width of your first item, but it won't dynamically adjust.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior is to take the width of the longest option inside the select. If you want, you can't set a fixed width `width : 100px`. If you want to make this dynamically, you are going to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're out of luck...Cross browser, the width of the drop down list is entirely determined by the length of the longest item. The two approaches to control the width of the list are to:

1. Cut down the length items (not really a solution)
2. Code your own dropdown box control, using Javascript, have a look [here](http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect/)

Typically you should be able to implement a custom solution using `<ul>` in a semi-similar way to how they're used for drop down menus, but implementing JS to detect sub item click events and change the top level `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

add a `span` in your html and use this JQuery code:

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/HVHV2/3/)

HTML

```
<span id="checkW" style="display:none;"></span>
```

JQuery

```
$( "#checkW" ).text($( "#drpCategory option:selected" ).text());
$( "#drpCategory" ).width($( "#checkW" ).width()+30);
$( "#drpCategory" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( "#drpCategory option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).text() + " ";
    });
    $( "#checkW" ).text( str );    
  })
.change(function(){
    $( "#drpCategory" ).width($( "#checkW" ).width()+30);
});
```